# Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/edit/(?P<entry>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to build an wiki page, already searched through other posts but couldn't solve my problem, someone can help?
I'm getting the following error: Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/edit/(?P[^/]+)/$']

Basically what it is, is an edit page to edit an wiki entry, the button to edit the entry is located at entry.html, this is supposed to send the entry name as a parameter to edit.url then i edit it and send through POST the new content to override the actual content of the entry.

Here is my views.py

```
def edit(request, entry):

if request.method == 'POST':
    content = request.POST.get('edit')
    util.save_entry(entry, content)
    
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "entry": markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(entry)),
        "title": entry
    })
else :
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
    "entry": entry
    })
```

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views    
app_name = "encyclopedia"
urlpatterns = [
  path("", views.redirect, name="redirect"),
  path("wiki", views.index, name="index"),
  path("wiki/search/", views.search, name="search"),
  path("wiki/newentry", views.new, name="new"),
  path("wiki/edit/<str:entry>/", views.edit, name="edit"),
  path("wiki/<str:entry>", views.entry, name="entry")
]
```

And my edit.html

```
{% extends 'encyclopedia/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}
Edit Page
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form action="{% url 'encyclopedia:edit' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

<label for="edit">Edit {{ entry }}</label>
<textarea id="edit" name="edit" style="display: block; height: 70%;"></textarea>
<button type="submit">Edit</button>
{% endblock %}
```

I forgot to put my entry.html, this is the page where the edt4it button is located, who redirects to the edit.html via GET.

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
   {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{{ entry|safe }}

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url'encyclopedia:edit'entry=title%}">Edit Entry</a>

 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a value for the `entry` parameter, this is likely the `entry` parameter:

```
<form action="{% url 'encyclopedia:edit' entry=entry %}" method="POST">
```

The error says that it can not find a view with the name `encyclopedia:edit` with *no* parameters, which is correct, since it has a parameter `entry`. You thus need to pass this to the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to put my entry.html, i would like to submit the link via GET on my entry page, there's some way to do this? Or has to be via POST?

Comment: @Brunol55: The HTTP standard says that a GET request is not allowed to have *side effects*. So editing an entry in the database should normally be done with a POST/PATCH/PUT/...

Comment: But it has to be via POST, or its better t be via POST, but what I can't understand is why it won't accept the entry on this path("wiki/edit/<str:entry>/", views.edit, name="edit") but it accepts on my entry path path("wiki/<str:entry>", views.entry, name="entry"), I just wanted to understand that better.

Comment: @Brunol55: it is *required* (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/188861/166310). It would also be unsafe since an internet crawler makes GET requests and could thus "by accident" edit/remove/... an entry. Furthermore for a GET request, Django will not perform CSRF validation.

Comment: I think I didn't explained myself or we are talking about differents parts of the problem, my edit.html has a form which has a POST method wich is used to edit an entry, <form action="{% url 'encyclopedia:edit' %}" method="POST"> its missing an entry=entry there, no problem with that, my doubt is on my entry.html on this button <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url'encyclopedia:edit'entry=title%}">Edit Entry</a> this button should take the user to the edit page via GET then in the edit page the user should edit the entry and send the data via POST and then it would update the database.

Comment: Well you render the two templates with different contexts. For the `entry.html`, you pass the title as `title`, and the "body" as `entry`, for the `edit.html`, you pass the title as `entry`.

Comment: Yes, I did this, but when i try to pass the title as entry to the edit.html I got the error that is on my post title.